# $\alpha(x)=\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1}$, $\tan(x)=\alpha^{-1}(x)$, $\sin{x}=\frac{\tan{x}}{\sqrt{1+\tan{x}^2}}$. Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi/2^-}\sin{x}=1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

Imagine we know nothing about trigonometric functions and we define the following function

$$\alpha(x)=\int_0^x (1+t^2)^{-1}$$

It can be shown that

- $\alpha'(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}>0$, so $\alpha$ is increasing.
- therefore, $\alpha^{-1}$ is defined on the image of $\alpha$ which is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$
- $\alpha$ is odd
- $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \alpha(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \alpha(x)$ exist

If we define

$$\pi=2\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \alpha(x)$$

then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \alpha(x)=-\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \alpha(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now let's define the following functions

$$\tan(x)=\alpha^{-1}(x)$$

$$\sin{x}=\frac{\tan{x}}{\sqrt{1+(\tan{x})^2}}$$

Let's say we want to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\sin{x}=1$.

We will need the following result

$$(\alpha^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha'(\alpha^{-1}(x))}=1+[\alpha^{-1}(x)]^2$$

Then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{\tan{x}}{\sqrt{1+(\tan{x})^2}}$$

**Now, the first thing I am unsure of is how to show, in the context of this problem, that**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \tan{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \alpha^{-1}(x)=\infty$$

Assuming we can show it, then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin{x}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

and by L'Hopital

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1+[\alpha^{-1}(x)]^2}{\frac{\alpha^{-1}(x)(\alpha^{-1})'(x)}{\sqrt{1+[\alpha'(x)]^2}}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\sin{x}}$$

That is, we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\sin{x}}$$

At this point, the solution manual says "so the limit is $\pm 1$.

**What is it that allows us to conclude this latter step?**

Comment: It's recommended to denote $(\tan x)^2$ as $\tan^2x$, not $\tan x^2$, which looks like $\tan(x^2)$.

Comment: The question asks about $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty^-} \sin{x}=1$ yet the sine function oscillates and does not go to a limit, so I cannot understand what the question is about.

Comment: Obviously a typo. The limit is for $x\to\pi/2^-$.

Comment: Since $\tan x\to\infty$ as $x\to\pi/2$ the ratio $\tan x/\sqrt {1+\tan^2x}\to 1$. I don't see why we need LHospital or something like that.

Comment: The limit of $\tan x$ as $x\to\pi/2$ follows from the fact that $\alpha(x) \to \pi/2$ as $x\to\infty $.

Comment: The approach in your question is one typical way to introduce circular functions in analysis. Dealing with periodic nature of these functions takes some effort in this approach. See details at https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/03/theories-of-circular-functions-part-2.html?m=0

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sure it is easy to see that what the limit of $\tan{x}$ is simply with the information we have about $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$. But I have trouble showing such a result analytically, in this case likely at the level of $\epsilon$ $\delta$.

Comment: You should use theorems to evaluate limits. And use $\epsilon, \delta $ to prove those theorems. You can show that $\tan x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ and use $\tan(\pi/2-x)=1/\tan x$ for all $x$ with $0<x<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \sin x
$$
exists, we can call it $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \frac{1}{\sin x} = \frac{1}{L}.
$$

Since you proved that these two are equal,
$$
L = \frac{1}{L}, 
$$
which is equivalent to the polynomial equation
$$
L^2 - 1 = 0, 
$$
which only has solutions $L = \pm 1$.

Is this what you're looking for?